# How to create application restricted folder

Tags: windows, security, winapi, file-permissions

I need to create a temporary folder that will be accessed from the application only. 
It means that even current user and system administrator are not able to open it from the Explorer. 
While application is running, there'll be some files put into it. Once it's terminated, folder and all its content are deleted (again programmatically, no manual delete ability).

P.S. I found few posts here but there are no proper solution given yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot stop admin reading your files

Comment: Only restricted from Explorer? Hmmm. So access from cmd is allowed? This is right 'security'. :-)

Comment: I removed the delphi tag because it's just a Windows question

Answer (score 3):

Windows security does not work that way.  You cannot restrict access by **application**, only by **user**.  If you want only your app to have access to a given resource then you have to create a new user account, configure the resource to grant access to only that user, and then run your app using that user, or at least have your app impersonate that user when needed.  Files/folders are securable objects, and Windows security is based on user accounts.